# Error : The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I made a **seeder** file to add data in the **MongoDB** database but getting this error,
`` Error : The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string. ``
students file cotaints students data and Student file is model file,
If anyone please helps me with this...

**Seeder.js**

```
const students = require("./data/students");
const Student = require("./models/Student");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

dotenv.config("../.env");
connectDB();

const importData = async () =>{
    try{
        await Student.deleteMany();
        await Student.insertMany(students)
        console.log("data imported");
        process.exit();
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error : "+err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

const destroyData = async () =>{
    try{
        await Student.deleteMany();
        console.log("data destroyed");
        process.exit();
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error : "+err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

if(process.argv[2] === "-d"){
    destroyData();
}else{
    importData();
}
```

here is my connection file
**db.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = async () =>{
    try{
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_URI,
            {
                useCreateIndex: true,
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true
            })
            console.log(`mongoDB connected successfully`);
    }catch (err){
        console.log(`Error : ${err.message}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Comment: make sure `mongoose.connect()` is receiving the right params. Is `process.env.ATLAS_URI` defined?

Comment: yes, it is receiving the right params and `process.env.ATLAS_URI` also defined

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be the issue:

The functions are defined as `async`, so they return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but you are calling them without waiting for the Promise to be fulfilled or rejected, specially in the case of `connectDB()`.

Try adding an `await` statement before the `connectDB()` call, like this:

```js
await connectDB();

//... the rest of the code
```

What it must be happening is that the call to connect is done after the main part of the program ran and finished, but you need the DB to be connected before importing/destroying the data, right?